# Formula's Not Updating Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a formula which copies from a specified cell in another workbook into the selected cell in the current workbook like this:

`='\\SERVER\FOLDER$\DEPARTMENT\[DEPARTMENT.xlsx]Sheet1'!D3`
Now this formula works for some parts of the spreadsheet but not all and I have no idea why.

I have set the workbook to automatically update formulas and that hasn't changed anything. I saw someone mention `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F9` and this hasn't updated anything as well as `Ctrl+Alt+F9`.

Please, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the said "Department.xlsx" file? Excel will never update values of external references if the excel file is not opened.

Comment: The file is fine, is there a way to get it to update with out creating a VBS script?

Comment: You may want to include what kind of error displayed in the cells containing that formula. Different errors give different clue to what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Formula don't have anything special to pull.

*It's simply pulling the Cell D3 value from Sheet 1 of Workbook Department, resides in subsequent Folder shown in the Formula.*

And CTRL+Alt+F9,, calculate All Worksheets in ALL OPEN WORKBOOKS, regardless of whether they have changed since the last calculation.

Also, Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9,, rechecks Dependent Formulas, and then calculates all cells in All Open Workbooks, including cells not marked as needing to be calculated.

**NB:** Load the Screen Shot.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, is there a better way to pull the data from that cell from a closed workbook without a vba script / macro?

Comment: @JaySterling,, check my new answer, help you to get data from closed Workbook.

Answer (score 0):

*I can suggest you a Dynamic method, to retrieve Data from the closed Workbook. But, this Method needs small support of VBA Code.*

**Part 1:**

Create this Function.

```
Function Evalluate(Ref As String)

   Application.Volatile
     Evalluate = Evaluate(Ref)

End Function
```

**Note**, *always spell the Function name little different (as I did EVALLUATE).*

**Part 2:**

**Do the followings in the Sheet where you want to pull Data from Closed Workbook**.

1. Write the Formula in any blank Cell like B2, but don't prefix it with = sign like below.

   *'\SERVER\FOLDER$\DEPARTMENT[DEPARTMENT.xlsx]Sheet1'!D3*
2. Go to the Formulas tab, and hit Define Name, assign a name to Cell B2, for example **NewResult**, and under *Refers To*, write *= Evalluate($B2)*.
3. Then, go to cell C2, and write *= NewResult*.
4. Drag down till is required.

This is the best possible method allows, to pull Data from the Closed Workbook and the best part is, It's working successfully.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Thanks, part 1 is done in the original (closed workbook) or new workbook?

Comment: In the Workbook (New Book), where you are pulling Data from the CLOSED Wbook. And don't forget to VOTE the answer.

Comment: i just get an error each time `#NAME?`

Comment: The Function Name is Evalluate and inside it has Evaluate command, Check this,, Evalluate = Evaluate(Ref) the ONLY DIFFERENCE is 2 LL on left of = sign and 1 L to the Right. Just Check it. On my Sheet It's working without any problem !!